How to copy a bitmap to my window buffer?
My program creates a window with the Windows API. I allocate a memory region with the VirtualAlloc() function, and with two for loops i iterate through it and change the RGB values of each pixel to cover the whole client are with a color.
After filling the buffer with the RGB data, i draw a rectangle to it, iterating again but just in a specific region of the buffer.
When the buffer is ready, the function StretchDIBits() displays the content of the buffer to the screen.
Is there a way to copy a HBITMAP image to my buffer?
Unfortunately i'm still a beginner and i'm still practicing and studying as selftaught, so i'm aware that there are probably tons of things i still don't know that will probably answer my question right away.

Use CreateDIBSection() instead of VirtualAlloc() to allocate your pixel buffer. This will give you both an HBITMAP handle to the DIB and a raw pointer to the DIB's pixels. You can then SelectObject() that HBITMAP into a memory HDC and draw on the HDC or in the raw buffer as needed.
To draw another HBITMAP onto your DIB, select the other HBITMAP into another memory HDC and then BitBlt()/StretchBlt() it into your DIB's HDC as needed.
You can then StretchDIBits() or StretchBlt() your DIB onto your window.
